# A question about Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology, mayer-vietoris-sequence

Let $A$ and $B$ be two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n>1$), with $A \cup B=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\cap B\not=\emptyset$. There is a version of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for reduced homology that implies:
$$...\widetilde{H}_1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{Z})\to \widetilde{H}_0(A\cap B,\mathbb{Z})\to \widetilde{H}_0(A,\mathbb{Z})\oplus\widetilde{H}_0(B,\mathbb{Z})\to\widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{Z})...     $$is exact. Do you know any reference for this version?

The answer should be in the relative homology groups (Hatcher pg 115) and the relative version of Mayer-Vietoris sequence (Hatcher pg 150). This is suggested by the discussion mentioned by
HallaSurvivor, but I don't see clearly!

Comment: If that were the case then either $A$ or $B$ would be empty, as $\mathbb R^n$ is connected.

Comment: Sorry! I corrected.

Comment: Sorry! I don't see. It should be deduced from the relative homology groups (Hatcher pg 115) and the reduced Mayer-Vietoris (Hatcher pg 150), as suggested in the discussion you mentioned, but I don't see clearly.